# JSON Parsing Sub Items VB.net using Newtonsoft

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

I've been fighting with this all weekend.  I'm trying to parse/deserialize my JSON using the Newtonsoft tools.

I am able to get to the top level data (EventID and EventName) with no troubles.

I've been scouring the examples and other posts for help getting to the ROOMS array on info.  The rooms and sessions will have 0-many items in the json set.

---

MY JSON:

```
{
    "EventID": 123,
    "EventName": "Training Camp",
    "Rooms": [
        {
            "RoomID": 12,
            "RoomName": "Main Ballroom"
        },
        {
            "RoomID": 256,
            "RoomName": "East Hall"
        }
    ],
    "Sessions": [
        {
            "SessName": "Session One",
            "ScheduleID": 1682,
        },
        {
            "SessName": "Session Two",
            "ScheduleID": 1683,
        }
    ]
}
```

---

My code:

```
Public Class JSONEvent
    Public EventID As Integer
        Public EventName As String
        Public RoomsArray As List(Of JSONRooms)
End Class

Public Class JSONRooms
    Public Property RoomName As String
    Public Property RoomID As String
End Class
```

in Form1:

```
Dim obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of JSONEvent)(JsonData)
messagebox.show(obj.eventid)
messagebox.show(obj.eventname)

Dim TheEvent As JSONEvent = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of JSONEvent)(JsonData)
TheEvent.RoomsArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of JSONRooms))(TheEvent.roomname) 'this I can't get right
```

Can someone please help me to access these data elements?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Jeff

Comment: Dont parse it, deserialize it

Answer (score 0):

```
    <Serializable> _
    Public Class Room
        Public Property RoomID() As Integer
            Get
                Return m_RoomID
            End Get
            Set
                m_RoomID = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_RoomID As Integer
        Public Property RoomName() As String
            Get
                Return m_RoomName
            End Get
            Set
                m_RoomName = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_RoomName As String
    End Class
    <Serializable> _
    Public Class Session
        Public Property SessName() As String
            Get
                Return m_SessName
            End Get
            Set
                m_SessName = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_SessName As String
        Public Property ScheduleID() As Integer
            Get
                Return m_ScheduleID
            End Get
            Set
                m_ScheduleID = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_ScheduleID As Integer
    End Class
    <Serializable> _
    Public Class JSONEvent
        Public Property EventID() As String
            Get
                Return m_EventID
            End Get
            Set
                m_EventID = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_EventID As String
        Public Property EventName() As String
            Get
                Return m_EventName
            End Get
            Set
                m_EventName = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_EventName As String
        Public Property Rooms() As List(Of Room)
            Get
                Return m_Rooms
            End Get
            Set
                m_Rooms = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_Rooms As List(Of Room)
        Public Property Sessions() As List(Of Session)
            Get
                Return m_Sessions
            End Get
            Set
                m_Sessions = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_Sessions As List(Of Session)

    End Class
```

and in c#

```
[Serializable]
public class Room
{
    public int RoomID { get; set; }
    public string RoomName { get; set; }
}
[Serializable]
public class Session
{
    public string SessName { get; set; }
    public int ScheduleID { get; set; }
}
[Serializable]
public class JSONEvent
{
    public string EventID { get; set; }
    public string EventName { get; set; }
    public List<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
    public List<Session> Sessions { get; set; }

}


    // your code should work except the whole object should be deserialized at once.   


        JSONEvent obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JSONEvent>(JsonData);
        messagebox.show(obj.EventID);
        messagebox.show(obj.EventName);
        // check the array
        if(obj.Rooms != null && obj.Rooms.Count > 0)
        {
            messagebox.show(obj.Rooms[0].RoomID.ToString());
            messagebox.show(obj.Rooms[0].RoomName):
        }
```

Comment: I got lazy and wrote it in C# then ran it through a code converter.

Comment: :)  Thank you for the help.   I am going to try this approach out.

Comment: I see the classes, but how to I access the data?